# Exception adding element to observablecollection property of dynamic variable

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, dynamic, observablecollection

I'm implementing a flexible processor to dynamically create some data via a template approach.  Everything working well until... I need to add elements to an `ObservableCollection<item>` and I'm referencing the object containing the collection as a dynamic.

So I have this:

```
dynamic componentItem = Activator.CreateInstance(targetType);
```

targetType (`UxBillingLineItem`) contains this property which is initialized in the default constructor:

```
public ObservableCollection<UxBillingLineItem> ComponentServices { get; set; }
```

(The nesting is deliberate)

I create an element to add to this collection:

```
object comp = Activator.CreateInstance(targetType);
```

Then I do this to add it:

```
componentItem.ComponentServices.Add(comp);
```

But I get this exception:
`The best overloaded method match for 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<UxBillingLineItem>.Add(UxBillingLineItem)` has some invalid arguments"

Edit...
I've looked at doing `Convert.ChangeType(comp, targetType)` but that still returns object, not targetType and returns the same error.
Also looked at:

```
public T ConvertType<T>(object input)
{
  return (T)Convert.ChangeType(input, typeof(T));
}
```

but that still needs a type at compile time, not a variable.

Comment: How can you be sure that `targetType` is the same in both cases?

Comment: targetType is a parameter to the routine.  Earlier in the process I have done ProcessMap.TargetType = typeof(UxBillingLineItem); and passed the type into the routine.

Answer (score 1):

The problem occurs because you can't add a `System.Object` to a strongly typed `ObservableCollection<UxBillingLineItem>`.  To address this, your comp variable needs to be typed as `UxBillingLineItem`.  *e.g.*:

```
UxBillingLineItem comp = (UxBillingLineItem)Activator.CreateInstance(targetType);
```

Comment: UxBillingLineItem type is a parameter to this routine.  So it's not possible to write the code you suggest.

Comment: (freakin 5 minute rule..)  The intent is to have a single method that can do similar processing with different target types.  So it's not possible to write the code you suggest and accomplish my goal.  I'd rather not have to change the definition of the various target types to have ObservableCollection<object>.

Comment: Do your target types have a common base type other than object?  If not, why do you think that you should be able to store them in a single strongly typed collection of some other type?

Comment: Thanks. There are different target types.  UxBillingLineItem contains a collection of UxBillingLineItems.  UxSomeOtherType contains a collection of UxSomeOtherType.  Just seems like there should be a way to add items to the collection parametrically.

Comment: Is there some reason that generics wouldn't work for this?  If you're not sure, perhaps you could elaborate on your end goal?

Comment: Awesome!  Yes, generics will work.  My method now has this signature and I can use the T type to create my target objects.  Thanks! private List<T> CreateBillingItemsFromMap<T>(ref RatingData ratingData, dynamic processMap, Hashtable propertyMap) where T : new()

Answer (score 0):

Nicole Calinoiu provided the best answer - generics.  I modified my method to use a generic type and everything works as expected.

private List`<T`> CreateBillingItemsFromMap`<T`>(ref RatingData ratingData, dynamic processMap, Hashtable propertyMap) where T : new()